# Scheme efficiency structure

Tags: scheme

I was wondering if we interpreters were cheating to get better performance. As I understand, the only real datastructure in a scheme is the cons cell.

Obviously, a `cons` cell is good to make simple datastructure like linked list and trees but I think it might get make the code slowlier in some case for example if you want to access the `cadr` of an object. It would get worse with a data structure with many more elements...

That said, may be scheme `car` and `cdr` are so efficient that it's not much slowlier than having a register offset in C++ for example.

I was wondering if it was necessary to implement a special datastructure that allocate native memory block. Something similar to using `malloc`. I'm talking about pure scheme and not anything related to FFI.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand, the only real datastructure in a scheme is the cons cell.

That’s not true at all.

R5RS, R6RS, and R7RS scheme *all* include vectors and bytevectors as well as pairs/lists, which are the contiguous memory blocks you allude to.

Also, consider that Scheme is a minimal standard, and individual Scheme implementations tend to provide many more primitives than exist in the standard. These make it possible to do efficient I/O, for example, and many Schemes also provide an FFI to call C code if you want to do something that isn’t natively supported by the Scheme implementation you’re using.

It’s true that linked lists are a relatively poor general-purpose data structure, but they are simple and work alright for iteration from front to back, which is fairly common in functional programming. If you need random access, though, you’re right—using linked lists is a bad idea.

Comment: I guess that sums it up to what I was thinking, I forgot about vectors thought. For example, the vectors can be implemented using lists. It would be inneficient but it wouldn't change much how the program is working. As long as the interface (functions) is identical for most scheme, then it can be implemented in anyway under the hood for performance. Like hash-table can be implemented in an assoc-list but that's kind of bad. But interpretters could handle that on their own.

Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Also, the term "interpreter" is basically dead; compiling/interpretation is an extremely blurry spectrum, and it's nonsensical to speak of an "interpreted language." Ooh, I'm crabby today. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First off. There are many primitive types and many different compound types and even user described types in Scheme.

In C++ the memory model and how values are stored are a crucial part of [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf). In Scheme you have not have access to the language internals as standard, but implementations can do it to have a higher percentage of the implementation written in Scheme.

The standard doesn't interfere in how the implementation chooses to store data so even though many imitate each other with embedding primitive values in the address and otherwise every other value is a object on the heap it doesn't need to be. Using pairs as the implementation of vectors (arrays in C++) is pushing it and would make for a very unpopular implementation if not just a funny prank.

With R6RS you can make your own types it's even extendable with [records](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-7.html):

```
(define-record-type (node make-node node?)
  (fields 
    (immutable value node-value)
    (immutable left node-left))
    (immutable right node-right)))
```

`node?` would be disjoint and thus no other values would be `#t` other than values made with the constructor `make-node` and this has 3 fields instead of using two `cons` to store the same.

Now C++ has perhaps the edge by default when it comes to storing elements of the same type in an array, but you can in many ways work around this. Eg. use the same trick as you see in [this video about optimizing java for memory usage](https://youtu.be/88-szpeNfrU). I would have started by making a good data modeling with records and rather worried about the performance when they become an issue.